# ASP.NET / UserControl, ViewState and losing Property values

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, properties, viewstate, ext.net

This is about ASP.NET, ViewState, UserControls and losing the values of my properties. It is a classic question by now, I know, and even though I have searched here and on Google for a resolution to this problem, I haven't succeeded. On the contrary, the more I test different things, the less I understand it seems.

On top of this I am using ext.net and their so called DirectMethod's but I don't think that has much to do with this problem. There are numerous questions I have.

**The UserControl**

I have a UserControl, Customers.ascx, that contains some Properties. The "most" important is *_CustomerId*. The _CustomerId is set in code-behind, in ext.net's "DirectMethod" like this (code below from the Page Customers.aspx):

```
    [DirectMethod]
    public void SetCustomer()
    {
        RowSelectionModel sm = GridPanel2.SelectionModel.Primary as RowSelectionModel;

        if (sm.SelectedRow != null)
        {
            uint customerId = uint.Parse(sm.SelectedRow.RecordID);
            customer_modify._CustomerId = customerId;
        }
    }
```

The "customer_modify" is the instance of the UserControl as defined in Customers.aspx (a Page, not a UserControl):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH_center" runat="server">
    <CP:Customer ID="customer_modify" runat="server" _IsCreateMode="false" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />   
</asp:Content>
```

In that Page, Customers.aspx, I have ext.net GridPanel that lists the Customers and when I click the rows in the GridPanel the (Direct)method SetCustomer is executed.

As you can see in the *SetCustomer*-method, the property "_CustomerId" is updated with an uint, so let's take a look at the Property in the UserControl:

```
    public uint _CustomerId 
    { 
        get
        {
            object o = ViewState["_CustomerId"];
            if (o == null)
                return 0;
            return (uint)o;
        }
        set
        {
            object o = ViewState["_CustomerId"];
            ViewState["_CustomerId"] = value;
            SetCustomer();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I am using the ViewState-thingie and it was my hope that the state, ie the value of the properties would be remembered. They are not.

When I click a Row in the GridPanel *the first time* I can see (by breaking) that the `ViewState["_CustomerId"] == null` which is alright. I see thereafter that the setter for _CustomerId is executed and that the `ViewState["_CustomerId"]` is assigned the RecordID (uint).

I now click another Row in the GridPanel and the SetCustomer-method is executed again. I break in the setter for _CustomerId and take a look at what the `ViewState["_CustomerId"]` is BEFORE assigning it. **It is 0, but I expect it to be the value from the previous Row clicked.**

Why is it 0? What am I missing?

**Also:**

I actually have two of their UserControls on the Page, the other one named "customer_create":

```
<ext:Window 
        ID="Window_CreateNewCustomer" 
        runat="server" 
        Icon="New"
        Title="Skapa ny kund" 
        Hidden="true"
        Width="480"
        Height="370"
        Modal="true">

        <Content>
            <CP:Customer ID="customer_create" runat="server" Title="Skapa ny kund" _IsCreateMode="true" />
        </Content>
</ext:Window>
```

What disturbs me is that each and every time I click on a Row in the GridPanel the Page_Load in the UserControl *is executed twice*, even though I am only updating one of them in the SetCustomer()-method.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewState` is serialized, enciphered and sent to the client as a hidden form field so that it may be reconstituted when something triggers a form submission.  A `[DirectMethod]` does not go through form submission (it's processed as an AJAX call), so it can neither read nor write `ViewState` data, unless round-tripping of this data is specifically requested with `ViewStateMode.Enabled`.

On any given request directed to a form, the `Load` event will be fired from the Page, and thus received by every user control on the page that subscribes to the event at the expected phase of the [page processing lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) -- whether it's two instances of one `UserControl`or two different `UserControl`s, it's two subscribers and therefore two calls (one to each instance).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. that led me in the right way. The solution is easy, you just add "ViewStateMode=Ext.Net.ViewStateMode.Enabled" to the DirectMethod-attribute, like this: [DirectMethod(ViewStateMode=Ext.Net.ViewStateMode.Enabled)]. In a quick test I just made, the ViewState is saved as expected =)

Comment: The thing with Page_Load executing twice even though Im just updating one UserControl... Can you say a few words on that? =)

Comment: I'll just add a quick comment to confirm, but yes... by default ViewState is not sent in a DirectMethod or DirectEvent request in Ext.NET. As you discovered, you can override this functionality by setting ViewStateMode=Enabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer i was search every where ! and worked fine for me  !